# Maze Generator in Java

Tags: java, depth-first-search, maze

The problem I need to solve is that I have to create a java program that generates randomly an ASCII maze ( that is with characters) . I have written a maze class , however I am stuck in creating the Depth first Search algorithm as I do not know how to go about it

my code is this :

```
public class Maze {
    int width;
    int height;
    char elements[][] = new char[width][height];

    public Maze(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public char[] GenerateMaze(){
        for(int i=0;i<width;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<height;j++){
                elements[i][j] = '#'
            }
        }
        return DepthFirstSearch(elements);
    }

    public char[] DepthFirstSearch(char elements[][]){

    }    
}
```

Comment: So your question is: **how to implement DFS?** You could find this info in graph-related paragraphs of books about algorithms. Also you will get a lot of help in tutorials if you just google **DFS java implementation**.

Comment: will you elaborate more?

Comment: I see an empty DepthFirstSearch method. Have you tried anything? You say you are stuck, but we don't see what you tried and what isn't working. Try to google about the subject.

Comment: The DFS algorithm for a maze  is straightforward.  1) See how many paths I can take.  2) If more than one path, turn right.  3) If one path, move.  4) If dead end, backtrack to last spot where there are multiple paths, and take the next right turn.  Follow these steps until you reach the end of the maze.